# What is the origin of the term "first contact"?

Tags: history-of, science-fiction-genre, first-contact, etymology

This term has a long history in Star Trek:
[Star Trek: First Contact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_First_Contact)
[ST:TNG episode "First Contact"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_Contact_(Star_Trek:_The_Next_Generation))
[First Contact Day](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/First_Contact_Day)

Also:
[Stargate: Atlantis episode "First Contact"](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/First_Contact)

Does this term originate in Star Trek or was it used in previous sci-fi works or does it predate sci-fi in discussing initial contact between cultures.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Actually, the first use of *this exact phrase*, at least in printed works, was in **1875**, according to Google's handy Ngram Viewer:

- [Term "First Contact" in the English corpus, between 1500 AD and present](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%22first+contact%22&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1500&year_end=2015&corpus=15&smoothing=3)

This was used in an astronomical sense, in the *Monthly Notices of the Royal Astronomical Society* :

- [Volumes 1874-1875](https://books.google.ca/books?id=SZEOAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA99&dq=%22first%20contact%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=QeqSVeqMAoL2yQS1u4HgDA&ved=0CCYQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22first%20contact%22&f=false)

But for usage in the desired sense of *"initial contact between cultures"*, the very first appearance was in the (rather lengthy) title of the following book:

- *[With a Prehistoric People, the Akikuyu of British East Africa, Being Some Account of the Method of Life and Mode of Thought Found Existent Amongst a Nation on Its **First Contact** with European Civilisation: With Illustrations and a Map](https://books.google.ca/books?id=vmebPgAACAAJ&dq=%22first+contact%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ZOuSVeLAIoecyATNsYLgBw&ved=0CE4Q6AEwCQ)*

by W. Scoresby Routledge and Katherine Routledge, first published **1910**.

These instances predate the term's first appearances in [science fiction](http://www.jessesword.com/sf/view/455), i.e. Murray Leinster's 1935 novella ***[Proxima Centauri](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?47474)*** and his 1945 novelette ***[First Contact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_Contact_(novelette))***.

In the former, we have the passage

> He had piloted the Adastra to its **first contact** with the civilization of another solar system...

which provides the first usage of the phrase in science fiction (in the desired sense).

(Thanks to @user14111 for the *Proxima Centauri* reference, and for pointing out that a 1916 instance reported in a prior version of this answer may not have been correct.)

Comment: @ThePopMachine The difference between this answer and the others is that these are examples of the phrase "first contact" being used in a *non-sci-fi sense*; they mean first contact between two human cultures. I assumed, since this is SF&F, you meant first contact *with aliens* :)

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield:  I think it's pretty clear from the original question what my intent was and why this answer is correct.   A question about a term used commonly in SF where the answer *might* be "actually, this term predated SF" is totally in bounds.   Just like the answer to some Star Trek questions is "the has it roots in naval tradition for hundreds of years".    All that having been said, if someone wanted to synthesize the other answers into this one, it would make a more complete answer.

Comment: @ThePopMachine : I have synthesized the additional information from the other answers into this one, as requested.  :-)

Comment: An earlier non-SF use of the phrase can be seen in the [Southern Quarterly Review, Volume 4](https://books.google.com/books?id=imIAAAAAYAAJ&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&dq=%22first%20contact%22&pg=PA157#v=onepage&q=%22first%20contact%22&f=false) from July 1843, which speaks of "the results of the first contact of Roman and barbarian society".

Comment: Also, astronomical uses of the term for eclipses go back even further, see [p. 1104 of Philosophical Transactions of the Royal Society of London](https://books.google.com/books?id=UV5FAAAAcAAJ&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&dq=%22first%20contact%22&pg=PA1104#v=onepage&q=%22first%20contact%22&f=false) from 1670.

Comment: First time I've seen a "More than 20 comments posted in the past 3 days" auto-flag on a five-year-old post :-) The conversation between Praxis and user14111 seemed important, about **the validity of the 1916 reference**, on the basis of which apparently @ThePopMachine accepted this answer, but which may be incorrect and has now been removed - I've [preserved the discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111599/discussion-on-answer-by-praxis-what-is-the-origin-of-the-term-first-contact) for anyone interested in the details. Also, hi Praxis, long time no see!

Comment: @Randal'Thor : Hello, how are you?!  It has been some time indeed.  Thanks for cleaning up the comments.  The answer has been revised, as Google Books’ presentation of the source from 5 years ago no longer matches what appears today.  If ThePopMachines revisits the acceptance, that’s understandable of course.

Comment: Another early usage: the 1887 book "Austral Africa" by John Mackenzie has a chapter heading beginning on [p. 21](https://books.google.com/books?id=4w0RAwAAQBAJ&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&lpg=PA21&dq=%22first%20contact%22&pg=PA21#v=onepage&q=%22first%20contact%22&f=false) that says the chapter will be about "native life and industry" as well as "first contact with Europeans".

Comment: @Hypnosifl : Thanks for these.  I would posit that these older texts were not digitized in Google Books five years ago, but are now available.  I can work these into the answer with credit to you, but by all means please feel free to post an answer as you see fit. :-)

Answer (score 9):

According to the [Historical Dictionary of Science Fiction](https://sfdictionary.com/view/455), the earliest known occurrence of the term *first contact* in the science-fictional sense of "[t]he first meeting between two different intelligent species" was in the novella ["Proxima Centauri"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?47474) by [Murray Leinster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Murray_Leinster) (pseudonym of William F. Jenkins), which first appeared in the [March 1935 *Astounding Stories*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?57556+c) (available at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/stream/Astounding_v15n01_1935-03#page/n11/mode/2up)). The following quotation is from [page 21,column 2](https://archive.org/stream/Astounding_v15n01_1935-03#page/n21/mode/2up), of the original magazine publication, or p. 669 of Isaac Asimov's anthology [*Before the Golden Age*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?3890):

> He had piloted the *Adastra* to its first contact with the civilization of another solar system.

Answer (score 7):

As far as I know, the first use of this exact phrase was in 1945 (~20 years before *Star Trek*), in a short story by Murray Leinster called [First Contact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_Contact_(novelette)). This story has long been considered one of the best science fiction stories ever (it's in the ["Hall of Fame"](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0765305372), and is in a number of anthologies such as [this one](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/6359456-first-contact).)

In fact, the author's estate tried to [sue Paramount](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Estate_of_William_F._Jenkins_v._Paramount_Pictures_Corp.) for trademark infringement over *Star Trek: First Contact*. The court found that Leinster probably did coin the term, but in the interim decades, it had become too generic to trademark any more.

Comment: According to Wikipedia, that story is also the first appearance of a "universal translator."

Comment: Murray Leinster's ["First Contact"](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?41398) is a **novelette** (7500-17500 words), not a novel; it takes up 25 pages (559-583) in Groff Conklin's anthology [*The Best of Science Fiction*](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?4111)

Comment: I typed novel out of habit, my bad. I've seen the work described as both a "short novelette" and a "long short story" (the legal case calls it a short story). It's kinda right on the edge.